# Copy and insert X number of rows where X is based on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I just wondered if anyone knew how to copy and insert X number of rows where X is based on a cell value?
D18 has the number of rows I need inserting and Row 20 is the row I need to copy and insert that many times.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: dint you try google'ing something about this?

Comment: Welcome to S.O.! Please provide some code you have attempted to solve the problem. There are various resources for learning and I suggest starting out by using the macro recorder for this problem and then taking a look at the best practices in the Stack Overflow documentation. Update your question with the code you've attempted or feel free to ask another question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out,

```
Sub insertRow()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Range("D18").Value
    Range("A20").EntireRow.Insert
Next i
End Sub
```

Modify it if you need to..

Comment: @TomWorfolk Please mark the answer as correct to make this resolved. Thats how you tell Thanks here :)

Comment: @TomWorfolk Its on the left side of the answer.. I